# RSpec request spec test always returning empty response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm currently putting together a project on Rails (4.1.8) and am trying out writing RSpec request specs to test the api routes. Strangely however it also seems to return a empty response when running the test, however doing a direct request with Postman returns the json data as expected.

Request Spec:

```
# spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Tasks API', type: :request do
  render_views
  describe 'GET /tasks' do
    it 'returns tasks' do
      headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json"
      }
      get '/tasks', headers
      puts "Response: #{response}"
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(json).not_to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
Failure/Error: expect(json).not_to be_empty
       expected `[].empty?` to return false, got true
```

The Tasks Controller is setup as follows:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
    json_response(@tasks)
  end
```

Response Concern:

```
module Response
  def json_response(object, status = :ok)
    render json: object, status: status
  end
end
```

Spec Support:

```
module RequestSpecHelper
  # Parse JSON response to ruby hash
  def json
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

I had read similar questions which talk about a rende_views fix - however I've added that with no effect and also I thought you didn't need these when using Request specs as they should run through the full stack?  Can anyone shed some light, quite new to request specs and a bit puzzled.

Comment: add   `puts "All tasks: #{Task.count}"` and check the output, I'm pretty sure your test database is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `tasks` in your DB, that's why it is returning an empty array.

You need to create a `task` before calling `index` action.

Either you can create a factory using the [facatory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) gem for `Task` or you can call the `create` action of `TasksController` before calling `index` action:

```
# spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Tasks API', type: :request do
  render_views
  describe 'GET /tasks' do
    before do
      FactoryGirl.create(:task)
    end
    it 'returns tasks' do
      headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json"
      }
      get '/tasks', headers
      puts "Response: #{response}"
      expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      expect(json).not_to be_empty
    end
  end
end
```

**Reference FactoryGirl(Defining factories):**
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#defining-factories